# Offline conversion with Google client ID not as eCommerce transaction in Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, universal-analytics

I am working on a project to measure offline conversions with the new Universal Analytics from Google.

When a lead gets the status "order" in my custom made lead management system, we sent the earlier grabbed Google client ID with the code below to Universal Analytics. The upload is working, although Analytics sees it as an ecommerce transaction.

Does anyone know how I can modify the code or Analytics settings to make sure that Google Analytics sees it not as eCommerce transaction?

My code for uploading the Google Client ID to Analytics:

```
$ch = curl_init();      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.google-analytics.com/collect'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; InfoPath.2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "v=1&tid=UA-XXXXXXXX-42&cid=379445656".urlencode('.')."1380816256&t=transaction&tr=123.00&ti=43388&z=".time()); 
curl_close ($ch);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sees it as a eCommerce transaction because the hit type you're sending `t=transaction` is for transactions. If you're wanting to send an alternative hit type, take a look at google's documentation for the other alternatives - [Measurement Protocol Developer Guide - Sending Common Hit Types](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide#commonhits).

Comment: Thanks! The documentation gives the following alternatives for t: 'pageview', 'appview', 'event', 'transaction', 'item', 'social', 'exception', 'timing'. But should I take for an offline conversion?